# JWT token com spring, para autenticação de usuários

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Ao tentar validar este método: `Jws<Claims> parseClaimsJws = setSigningKey.parseClaimsJws(token);`, ele mostra esta exceção na tela

```
JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. 
JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
```

Preciso de validar o token do usuário.

Debugando.

Ao fazer o login ele gera este token: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIwMjY3OTUwMDYzNiIsImV4cCI6MTUyMjI3NjMxOX0.XBLiwl94He0ffVkf5TpcBKUob6PotuleSni5Hc9y8anPsES6WSO6f8Ki441UU_HGicyRAXmZKLBXsfQ2okFAqw`

Quando ele pesquisa por um país ele utiliza este token, Consulta feito segundos depois.

```
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIwMjY3OTUwMDYzNiIsImV4cCI6MTUyMjI3NjMxOX0.
XBLiwl94He0ffVkf5TpcBKUob6PotuleSni5Hc9y8anPsES6WSO6f8Ki441UU_HGicyRAXmZKLBXsfQ2okFAqw
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao debugar nas classes do jwt, ele dá erro nesta linha no método **DefaultJwtSignatureValidator**:

Então o jwt tem uma classe e métodos para ajustar e validar o token.

O problema é que ele está parando neste método nesta linha:

```
@Override
    public boolean isValid(String jwtWithoutSignature, String base64UrlEncodedSignature) {

        byte[] data = jwtWithoutSignature.getBytes(US_ASCII);

        byte[] signature = TextCodec.BASE64URL.decode(base64UrlEncodedSignature);

        return this.signatureValidator.isValid(data, signature);
    }
```

As variáveis **data** e **signatureValidator** estão diferentes.

Imagens:

[image: Variável data]

[image: Variável signature]

A variável **jwtWithoutSignature**, que chega no metodo da jwt, não é o token gerado, somente uma parte.

Erro na validação pelo site **https://jwt.io/**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Alterei a descrição com um valores do debug aonde eu acho que está ocorrendo o problema.

Comment: Mais uma descrição após debugar mais o código.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido.

Consegui sim.

Criando assim:

```
 private String token(UsuarioEntity usuario) {
     String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(usuario.getLogin()).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, "usuarioLogado").setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 5 * 60 * 1000)).compact();
 }
```

Buscando o token assim:

```
 Claims body = null;
 try {
    body = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("usuarioLogado").parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
 } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return body;
```

Pelo que eu vi estava gerando de com um tipo e tentando buscar de outro.

Valeu pessoal

Não sei aonde marca que foi resolvido